# How to debug stored procedure in Visual Studio without publishing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

Previously I developed everything DB related in SSMS but since I didn't have it setup with any source control I decided to move it into Visual Studio (where I develop everything else) as a Database Project.

This works quite well for most things but I would like to test and debug my stored procedures somehow without publishing the project. Is this possible and how is it done? The important thing is that data from the production DB should be accesible for the stored procedures.

Comment: As an aside, SSMS can be integrated with TFS (if that's what you're using for source control) using [this addin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/06c8e056-7f77-4a5c-9b8b-49318c143df8).

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio, open SQL Server Object Explorer (View-SQL Server Object Explorer). Find your database, right click and select "New Query".

You can run/test your sp using "exec spProcedureName".
You can use "Ctrl-Shift-E" as a shortcut to execute query.

Also, you can find your procedure under "Programmability-Stored procedures" and right click on it. If procedure has parameters, you'll get a pop-up window in order to enter params.

Comment: But this only works if the stored procedure has been published, right? Since I handle my stored procedures from the Database project it would be neat if I could test them out before publishing.

Comment: Youo can't test a stored proc until it exists. That would be like debugging your .net code prior to compiling it. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange Exactly, so is there a way of publishing it to a local copy of the DB (including data)?

Comment: No. Stored procs don't have data, that belongs to the database. You would have to have a recent copy of production to see those results.